# Share of students in/out of state

Tags: data.gov, collegescorecard

I'm looking for data on what share of students are in- or out-of-state, for each college/class. I'm guessing colleges do report this as it is covered in other reports from the NCES (for example, the Enrollment and Employees in Postsecondary Institutions reports). However, I can't seem to find any fields in the College Scorecard data documentation pointing to this.

Any ideas on whether it is possible to get this data?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered by sending an inquiry to `scorecarddata@rti.org`.

The asked-for data is indeed not included in the Scorecard data set, but it released by IPEDS. I found what I was looking for in the `EF*C` data files at https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter.

Comment: which dataset in IPEDS has this data?